# how to convert map<anydata> to json

Tags: type-conversion, ballerina

In my CRUD Rest Service I do an insert into a DB and want to respond to the caller with the created new record. I am looking for a nice way to convert the map to json.

I am running on ballerina 0.991.0 and using a postgreSQL.

The return of the Update ("INSERT ...") is a map. 
I tried with convert and stamp but i did not work for me.

```
import ballerinax/jdbc;

...

jdbc:Client certificateDB = new({
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/certificatedb",
    username: "USER",
    password: "PASS",
    poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 },
    dbOptions: { useSSL: false }
}); ...

var ret = certificateDB->update("INSERT INTO certificates(certificate, typ, scope_) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", certificate, typ, scope_);

// here is the data, it is map<anydata> 
ret.generatedKeys
```

map should know which data type it is, right?
then it should be easy to convert it to json like this:

```
{"certificate":"{certificate:
"-----BEGIN
CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIFJjCCA...tox36A7HFmlYDQ1ozh+tLI=\n-----END
CERTIFICATE-----", typ: "mqttCertificate", scope_: "QARC", id_:
223}"}
```

Right now i do a foreach an build the json manually. Quite ugly. Maybe somebody has some tips to do this in a nice way. 
It cannot be excluded that it is due to my lack of programming skills :-)

Answer (score 1):

The return value of JDBC update remote function is sql:UpdateResult|error.

The sql:UpdateResult is a record with two fields.  (Refer https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/sql.html#UpdateResult)

1. UpdatedRowCount of type int- The number of rows which got affected/updated due to the given statement execution
2. generatedKeys of type map - This contains a map of auto generated column values due to the update operation (only if the corresponding table has auto generated columns). The data is given as key value pairs of column name and column value. So this map contains only the auto generated column values.

But your requirement is to get the entire row which is inserted by the given update function. It can’t be returned with the update operation if self. To get that you have to execute the jdbc select operation with the matching criteria.  The select operation will return a table or an error.  That table can be converted to a json easily using convert() function.

For example: Lets say the certificates table has a auto generated primary key column name ‘cert_id’. Then you can retrieve that id value using below code.

```
int generatedID = <int>updateRet.generatedKeys.CERT_ID;
```

Then use that generated id to query the data.

```
var ret = certificateDB->select(“SELECT certificate, typ, scope_ FROM certificates where id = ?”, (), generatedID);
json convertedJson = {};
if (ret is table<record {}>) {
    var jsonConversionResult = json.convert(ret);
    if (jsonConversionResult is json) {
        convertedJson = jsonConversionResult;
    }
}
```

Refer the example https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/jdbc-client-crud-operations.html for more details.?

Comment: Hi Anupama, thanks for your fast response. This would work. I have that auto generated primary key. I don't want to  do an additional SQL call (Select) to the DB, when all the Information is already in the response of the INSERT (Update).

Comment: Since you already know the data you are inserting, only you need is the auto generated primary key. It will return from the update function(in the generatedKeys field). You will get the same information by issuing the second select function call. Since you have the required data already you can manually create the json after getting the auto generated Id from the update return value. You can maintain all the data in a ballerina map and then easily convert it to a json. Refer https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/json-record-map-conversion.html for more details on map to json conversion.